# How can I use the Variables Reference in vscode extension code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to use the variable in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables in the vscode extension source code.

How can I get the access to them? Anyone know it?

There is no direct method to get them on official website or github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any api access to the built-in variable resolver.  You will have to make your own.  Here is a good example from another extension [Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands):

https://github.com/usernamehw/vscode-commands/blob/master/src/substituteVariables.ts